# theta transformation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Which theta series do I have to consider in order to show that $$\sum_{\mu\in a}e^{-2\pi t(\mu+u)(\mu'+u')}=\frac{1}{|\sqrt{DNorm(a^2)}|t}\sum_{\nu\in a^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{D}})}e^{\frac{-2\pi}{t}\nu \nu'+2\pi i(\nu u+\nu'u')} \ \ (1)$$ ,where $u,u' \in \mathbb{C}$  , $a $ is an ideal in $K=Q(\sqrt{D}),D<0 .$
The  prime denotes the conjugate number . I considered the theta series $$\theta_a(\tau,\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{\lambda \in a}e^{2\pi i\tau(\lambda+\beta,\lambda+\beta)/2}e^{-2\pi i(\lambda+\beta/2,\alpha)} $$ 
 for $\beta=0$  , where $(\lambda+\beta,\lambda+\beta)=trace((\overline\lambda+\beta)(\lambda+\beta))=2Norm(\lambda+\beta)$  .

I think $\theta_a(-1/\tau,0,\alpha)$ should give the left hand side of (1) for $\tau=i/t$ .

I think the theta transformation formula for even lattices $M$ says

$$\theta_M(-1/\tau,-\beta,\alpha)=\frac{\tau}{i\sqrt{|M'/M|}}\sum_{\lambda \in M'}e^{2\pi i \tau(\lambda+\beta,\lambda+\beta)/2}e^{-2\pi i(\lambda+\beta/2,\alpha)}$$ , where $M'$ is the dual lattice of $M$ .

Thanks for the help .

Comment: $\mu' = $? And does $u'$ depend on $u$? I would expect $u'$ to be the complex conjugate of $u$ and the same for $\mu'$. Moreover, I would say that you have to consider $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = u$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  . Yes  c'  denotes the complex conjugate number of c.

Comment: In that case: Consider $\alpha = 0, \beta = u$ and observe that $(\lambda + \beta, \lambda + \beta) = (\lambda + \beta)(\lambda' + \beta')$. Renaming $\lambda$ to $\mu$ and setting $\tau = it$ gives you the left-hand-side.